# Account banned for 5 questions in 6 months

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions, post-ban, question-quality

I have been banned for 6 months, for having 5 questions in 6 months with only one having downvotes. My questions get marked as off topic even though I have read the rules and follow them perfectly to the best of my ability.

There is no way to fix the questions that don't have anything wrong, take a look for yourself and see.

Maybe 2 questions I have asked in the last year have deserved to be shut down.

[image]

[image]

Stack Overflow is the most strict by far of all the stack exchange sites. Every other site, I have never had any issue whatsoever. It is only on Stack Overflow where my questions get closed before they can even be read, and listed as off topic because of not having a problem statement (even though the problem statement is in clear English). Or they will be listed as a duplicate for a post that had nothing to do with it.

I guess the only solution is to make burner accounts for every programming question I have, while I can rest assured that every other stack exchange I participate in won't ban me for being productive which is sad.

It would be nice to learn how its possible to be banned for 6 questions in 5 months, where only one has been downvoted.

Comment: You have deleted content. What's visible on your account wouldn't get you banned, unless there's some stuff we don't see. And by the way... if you want a better reception on meta... I would suggest not making it sound like a rant. "toxic" "people don't read", whatever... won't do you any favors :/

Comment: There are maybe 2 questions that are > 6 months old that deserve to flag my account and I have no way to access them. Everything since then has been productive yet I am still shut down. Vanilla stackoverflow is indeed toxic when compared to the others which don't discriminate against users within seconds of opening a productive question.

Comment: John, "maybe" won't cut it here. The system will count ALL your contributions. Deleted, not deleted, old or new. A diamond mod might come here and give you a list of these deleted posts

Comment: @john then.... think everything is toxic and nothing can be made better. Your questions won't get a better standing with that attitude, unfortunately. That'll end as a self-fulfilling prophecy. Good luck

Comment: Even if my account was reinstated, I will still have to make burner accounts for every programming question I have due to the fact that they will be flagged against the account 50% or more of the time. Only for stackoverflow, all the other moderators and users of other sites seem to have no issue with my questions. I know this account will go no where at this point as far as programming questions, I simply want to share my experience.

Comment: 50% or more? You know there is the data explorer that can be used so people don't throw these stats around without proof. The real number is lower, far lower than half. So.... yeah :/... And btw, "burner accounts" can and will likely get you flagged and risk other accounts (mods have good tools for this). Maybe not the best way to go :/

Comment: The unfortunate part is that so many people expect SO to be a help desk, when nothing could be further from the truth.  Yes, the site doesn't do a good job of setting those expectations, but neither does that entitle you to charged language or threats of bypassing our quality standards.

Comment: I appreciate your input here, but I have done my best and been nothing but productive to the best of my ability after a few useless questions when my account first started. It seems on stackoverflow.com, unless you're an expert you aren't welcome. Again its only an issue on a single website in the stackexchange network, if I was such a problem the other sites would give me the same treatment.

Comment: @John I... disagree. Expectations are different with every site. Doesn't mean it's "toxic". Just means the expectations are different. So yes, there are differences. You can adapt to them, or you can just.... declare everyone else is the problem. I know which one is productive and which one isn't. Hopefully you'll realize it too. Remember Stack is **one** of your research tools. It's not meant to be the be all, end all, to **all** programming related questions.

Comment: Now that your deleted content is out..... 10 questions, 3 downvoted, 3 upvoted, total score of -10... 4 questions without votes (which isn't great either), and one question where you removed an answer by deleting your question (which counts against you badly)...... My point is **really** not to be an ass here. But.... if you were an automated algorithm and were offered that dataset, would you think that the user who posted those would be likely to post high quality content in the future? :/

Comment: All of this over an extended period of time. In addition you can check out this post for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980053/python-script-only-works-every-other-time-i-run-it
It was closed and stated as "off topic" due to the fact it didn't have reproducible code and no problem statement, even though both were provided ( I later edited it to provide trivial information on what to modify to reproduce) 
I could bring up more from other users and other accounts but I don't have the time, its obviously an issue with the users of that site.

Comment: @john I can't see that post, I don't have enough rep to see deleted content. The length doesn't matter. If you had someone who had the dataset I mention in my previous comment. How confident would you be the **next** question would be positive and well received? You seem to think there's a human that looked at your account and clicked "ban this dude". It's not. It's all automated, looking at your previous content

Comment: The question that caused the ban was upvoted multiple times in less than 15 minutes, in addition I tried to search for the answer to the issue and was unable to find it, hence why I asked. I won't waste any more of your time here, just note this when the next person comes along who has the exact same experience.

Comment: @Johndoe sure. WHen the next person comes in, entitled, ranting and not wanting to discuss, listen, or show any proof of anything... I'll likely do like I did here: try to engage positively and constructively, highlighting what's happening and how the person can be helped. Not many users come here **wanting** that. They just look for an outlet for "I've been banned, I'm angry rawr"

Comment: And..... as I said, be careful with burner accounts. Stack can and has banned IPs completely. Don't risk the whole network just cause you're sour :/. Seems like you've already been using them. Be careful. Best of luck for the future

Comment: I just want help sometimes when I can't find it after searching, thats all, and I will do so in any way possible. The proof has been posted, you don't have the rep to read it. I will re open the question for you.

Comment: @Patrice here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd585.png oh ...

Comment: @Johndoe with the link from rene, I can likely guess what happened on your question. You posted without the info to reproduce. Got closed. Added the info. Got impatient and deleted the question less than 24 hours after the edit, before you even had a chance to go through the reopen queue.... Maybe I'm wrong.  But if I'm not... that's... pretty expected. Not a great experience, don't get me wrong. But.... WAI for sure.

Comment: I was wrong. It DID go through the reopen queue before you deleted it. Seems like the community opted to keep it closed. Now... I'm not really sharp in python anymore... but maybe your example isn't to be considered "minimal"? at a glance, there is stuff in there I'm guessing could be trimmed

Comment: The entirety of what I added was "The nmap scan function takes an IP address as the host argument, hardcoding a couple ip addresses into the ip list will allow this issue to be reproduced." Even though this information is trivial to anyone who actually read the question, and I provided 100% of my code(which is a short script) needed to reproduce initially with a clear problem statement, it was still shut down. Simply browsing stackoverflow long enough you will see this is a recurring pattern

Comment: @John 100% of your code isn't a minimal example, in about 99% of the cases :/.

Comment: And.... why is "this happens a lot" has to be a pattern of the community being wrong, and not new users not knowing the quality standards? What I keep on saying is that there is a disconnect. The fact this happens a lot points to just such a disconnect. Users aren't aligned on what Stack means anymore. New users want a more lenient, free-er stack, and the old guard, who saw how **that** turned out whenever we tried it, is a bit more against it.

Comment: It seemed to be what was necessary for those in the comments who answered the question. This may not justify some of my other posts, but it is indeed a chronic problem for many users. This is partially the reason I suggest use burners because even if you do it perfectly, you still get flagged. It happened to me 3 days ago on a different account, it was marked as a duplicate to a question which was only slightly related and did not clearly have the information I requested. Luckily there are fast users who can answer the completely valid question in an answer or comment before it gets shut down.

Comment: There needs to be a bit more of an understanding of SO, and SE in general going on here.  Some of that is also going to require taking some personal responsibility for your own actions.  There's only so much we can tell you and teach you before we start going in circles.  Unless you're listening, we're talking at you, not to you.  So...ask yourself, what do you expect to happen by complaining about your ban?  For it to be lifted?  To learn why you were banned?  Or to complain that it's unfair and you'll just bypass it to stick it to the man?

Comment: I simply want this to be documented as I will be forced to ditch this account and use a new account for every single one of my questions, since I never know when I will need help and be surprised by an unwarranted ban based on things that are OLD.

Comment: I wish you all luck, and thanks for the input

Comment: Also, "validity", "legitimacy", and other confirmation-type words are often used as a defense against question curation.  Unfortunately, none of them are relevant when it comes to actually meeting our standards; having a problem and being able to meet our standards when asking a question are two different things.  Having a problem isn't a license to getting free help.

Comment: Well, ditch the account if you like; it won't make much of a difference, according to the info already available.  It'll just mean more time spent ensuring the system is aware of you, and to limit your ability to damage the site.

Comment: Well as you can see from the post I provided and undeleted, it met the standards thoroughly and was shut down for no apparent reason. With that, I must go now, I do appreciate the input and time of you all.

Comment: If it met the standards, it wouldn't have been closed.  So...no.  Your statement is incorrect.

Comment: @John... I already told you that burner accounts are risky. Meagar pointed out HE HAS CONFIRMATION you're doing it. Do you think that doing it **won't** result in bad stuff? cause... it will. then when it happens you'll scream and complain against Stack even more. And btw.... "standards thoroughly".... I already asked, is that **truly** minimal or not? I don't think it is at a glance. And if it isn't... then no, it's not our standards :/ Sucks, but that's how it is

Comment: 100 lines is minimal, just browse the site and see dozens upon dozens which aren't shut down which have much more than that. At this point we are all wasting time. Have a good weekend

Comment: @john .... minimal means "no extra cruft". Not "under a certain amount of lines". To prove certain problems, minimal will be 3 lines. For others, minimal will be 100. Minimal means "only contains what's needed to highlight the issue. No less, no more". If you misunderstood "minimal" to mean "small enough"...then yeah, no wonder it ended poorly

Comment: @johndoe: If stackoverflow is so terrible, then why do you come here to ask questions? Surely if we keep downvoting your questions and you end up deleting them you aren't having a good experience here. Why keep coming back?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, which is also contributing to the question ban: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/57714429) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/57152404) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/55124710) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/41939777))

Comment: Did you ever answer anything?

Answer (score 19):

You've opted to take your case to the community, so:

You're automatically blocked from asking because of a history of negatively received questions, *not* because of any action taken by a person.

There are also numerous blocked "burner accounts" (as you put it) on your IP address, that are clearly owned by you, because they've been reposting negatively scored questions containing the same code as some of your questions. I cannot say for sure, but that *may* count towards your automated question ban.

In addition to the "burner accounts", you have 5 deleted questions, in addition to the 5 undeleted questions visible in your profile:

- [closed, score -8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124710/can-someone-explain-n-grams-to-a-5-year-old-child)
- [closed, score -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939777/java-class-error-non-static-method-string-double-double-int-cannot-be-refere)
- [closed, score 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980053/python-script-only-works-every-other-time-i-run-it)
- [self-deleted with 1 answer, score 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714429/how-to-separate-nested-json-attributes-in-python-for-use-in-postgresql)
- [self-deleted, score 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152404/is-it-possible-to-scan-a-list-of-urls-in-zap)

The vast majority of your content has been either closed, deleted (often by you) or negatively received.

In total you have *two* questions which are open, undeleted, and with a positive score, vs *eight* questions which are closed and/or downvoted and/or deleted.

Comment: 2 negatively received + closed questions in nearly 3 years warrants a ban?

Comment: that amounts to 50% of your contribution @john. If someone were shouting irrelevant content in your ear half the time they're talking to you, how much time would you tolerate them?

Comment: It is preposterous. I have attempted to be as productive as possible in recent months. I have seen this happen to friends and numerous other accounts over my time here, its a chronic issue on a singular site on this network. Like I have said before, If you make one actual mistake and/or aren't an expert, you aren't welcome on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Johndoe... not to sound dismissive, but "I have the proof, I don't have time to show it'...... is something we hear VERY often here. And whenever we dig... we **never** see proof. What ends up happening more often than not is the expectations of new users (which, I'll be the first to say, Stack does an **awful** job of setting up) is very different than the quality standards. There's likely room to make it more seamless for **both** parties involved. But it's not by slinging "toxic" around that you'll help or change anything :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980053/python-script-only-works-every-other-time-i-run-it

Comment: I only say toxic because of the singular site. If I brought this upon myself for every other site I post on, then I would consider that it is 100% an issue that I caused. In my opinion, a couple of minor mistakes and closed questions, with productive activity in recent months, doesn't warrant a ban. In addition, questions are closed for reasons that are not true, as with the link I posted for whoever has the rep to read it.

Comment: Does the system not take into consideration every other site on the network which finds me somewhat productive? Why not?

Comment: @johndoe Why would it? Why is your ability to, say, [make beer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/) relevant to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Maybe the technical stack exchanges which I use such as unix, security, etc. might have relevancy to stackoverflow.

Comment: @johndoe And maybe that is factored in, and your behavior of using alternate accounts to circumvent your question ban, only to have *those* accounts banned, is working against you more than your good behavior elsewhere is helping you.

Comment: @johndoe *It is preposterous. I have attempted to be as productive as possible in recent months.* Your most recent question was marked as a duplicate. The one before it was closed. And the one before that has a score of -2. I'm not seeing your point here.